# execute ng serve pointing to the angular directory from current directory

Tags: node.js, angular, batch-file

working with angular2 App, and i am writing .bat scripts to automate the angular build and serving the application, as part of the ng serve. **I have to do like**

```
  c:\abc\edf>ng serve --server=d:\angualr2\demoApp
```

Here demoApp is angular2 and node_modules already installed i need to up the angulap app by my batch script.

**Where as everyone knows it works and working for me too.**

```
     d:\angualr2\demoApp>ng serve
```

Answer (score 1):

1. if you build the application, then you don't serve it with `ng serve`
2. the flag `--server` is unknown to me, and to the CLI documentation (`--help`)
3. If you have a path issue, start by goign into the right folder of your file explorer with `cd D:\angular2\demoApp` (not sure about it, I'm more of a Linux man)
4. `ng` works because NPM added it to your PATH. If you work on another computer, it won't work. Consider running with the local package with a npm command such as `npm run build`, where `build: "ng build --prod"`

Comment: This could be an altenate soluton. and I did it the approach.

Comment: Still expecting a better from the angularor javascript side to be done

Comment: I don't know why you expect more, Angular is a Javascript framework made for the client side. Don't expect it to be a whole server like Node is, that's not its purpose.